# Replace string in JS array without using native replace() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am stuck a bit with replacing string in js array. I am trying to log the arguments to see what is going on but am missing a piece of the puzzle.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dntreply/pc8y5un5/)

```
// - trying to look for substring in array 
// - if match is found 
// - replace substring without using the native method replace();

var div = $('.insert');

data = ["erf,", "erfeer,rf", "erfer"];
data = data.map(function (x) {
    return /""/g.test(x) ? x.replace(/""/g, "") : x
});

function fakeReplace(data, substr, newstr) {

//should show   ["erf,", "erfeer,rf", "erfer"];      
div.append("data before match replace = " + data);

    div.append("\<br>");
    div.append("substr = " + substr);
    div.append("\<br>");
    div.append("newstr = " + newstr);
    div.append("\<br>");

    return data.split(substr).join(newstr);
}

fakeReplace(data, "erf", "blue");

//should show ["blue,", "blueeer,rf", "blueer"];
div.append("data after fakeReplace is executed = " + data);
```

Comment: _but am missing a piece of the puzzle_ -> at least the error message in the console

Comment: `split()` is a string function and `data` is an array. Do you want to return a new array with replaced values or should you be turning the array into a string first?

Comment: I'd like to return the array with the new values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are treating `data` like a string in your function. You can use `map()` to return a new array with each element replaced.

```
function fakeReplace(data, substr, newstr) {
    return data.map(function(s) {
       return s.split(substr).join(newstr);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my fiddle and see that gets me much closer but the array isn't swapping out my values. http://jsfiddle.net/dntreply/pc8y5un5/7/

Answer (score 0):

```
      let myString = "Victor";
      let splitted = myString.split('');

      function replaceManual(a,b){

      for(let i = 0; i<= splitted.length-1; i++)
       {

          for(let j=i; j <=i;j++)
           {
             if(splitted[j]===a)
              {
                splitted[j]=b;
                return splitted;
              }
                else
              {
                break;
             }   
            }
          }
          }
   replaceManual('V','T');

   console.log(splitted.toString().replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, ''));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).